# Is there a visual representation of CallStack in VS .Net (instead of the in-built stacked representation)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, callstack

Is there a plugin available for Visual Studio .Net that gives a visual representation of the CallStack while debugging (instead of the stacked representation of method calls that is in-built in it)? (I am imagining something similar to an execution path we have in SQL server) This, imho, would help in visualizing the logic flow of the program.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's [CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979205.aspx) might help you.

Comment: I have been using the CLR Profiler since 1.1 and find it very good at living up to it's name

Answer (score 0):

There are other code profilers that might have what you are looking for.  The ones I know of are commercial ($) products.  Jetbrains and numega are two examples.

Frankly, I am at a loss to figure out why during execution/at a debug break you are not getting useful information from the call stack.

Note that you can get stack information from the CLR very easily.  I suspect there are some free/open source projects out there that have what you want.  I'll try to look around